# Parsing JSON From URL In Android

Tags: android, json, parsing, url

I am trying the parse the following JSON in android - http://cj1m.1.ai/test.json

At the moment, when running this code, my app crashes:

```
public String getJSON() throws IOException{
    String url = "http://cj1m.1.ai/test.json";

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    InputStream is = entity.getContent();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"utf-8"),8);
    String jsonText = reader.readLine();

    return jsonText;
}
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this?

Comment: what is the error/exception thrown back to you ? Add your stackTrace to the question

Comment: @SudhirMishra I am not quite sure how I get this

Comment: Make sure you are making the HTTP request in a separate thread, not on the UI thread.

Comment: @Cj1m every IDE has a LogCat. what error is logged in thate LogCat. Copy the error log only and add it here.

Comment: @KennyC is that the problem?

Comment: I don't know, please post all of your code and the log cat

Comment: @KennyC I have lots of code though

Comment: @KennyC I could post logcat

Comment: @KennyC `04-05 19:55:35.211: W/dalvikvm(26927): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ed8438)` This is the one part of the logcat file which looks like it has something to do with the problem

Comment: @Cj1m If you look through the Stacktrace, you'll see "Caused by..." line(sometimes more than one). The last one is more important one through which we can find the rootcause of the problem. Can you post the entire trace?

Comment: @Naveen How do I find the Stacktrace?

Comment: @Cj1m Stacktraces are available via LogCat, either in an IDE or via adb logcat on the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue might be because of incorrect JSON response format. Looks like the JSON response is incorrect in http://cj1m.1.ai/test.json. You can validate your JSON response in this URL - http://jsonlint.com/

Edit:

From your latest log, it is clear that you are trying to retrieve the JSON in the main thread which causes the app to crash. You need to make use of `AsyncTask` to perform network operations.

You can refer this code,

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
             // Escape early if cancel() is called
             if (isCancelled()) break;
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }
```

More details [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)!

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, the JSON is valid

Comment: Ahh ok. Can you post the entire stacktrace?

Comment: Sorry, how do I do this, do you mean post everything in the logcat?

Comment: Yes post everything from the logcat for the app.

Comment: Ok, need to post on pastebin because it's too much for the comment section: http://pastebin.com/eHc4RSBc

Comment: Which IDE do you use? Can you post the error trace only for that app?

Comment: If you use Eclipse IDE, create a Filter with your app's package name and run the app again. Once the app gets crashed get the trace from the filter and post it here.

Comment: it is from the filter

Comment: Can you try restarting your ADB server? you can do `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server`

Comment: You can find the adb tool in `<sdk>/platform-tools/`

Comment: You should search Google before asking each and every question.. Nobody is here to spoon feed you. Sorry!

Comment: From your log it is clear that you are trying to retrieve the JSON in the main thread. You should be using `AsyncTask`. Make the http call get request in `doInBackground` and parse the response there. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I will get back to you if I have any problems

Comment: Glad it helped.. I have updated the above answer and posted the code.. You can accept the answer and upvote it if it helped. Thanks!!

Comment: Works, thanks for helping me out (and for persevering with me)